# Unbind click event of an object coming after click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have `anchor` tag

```
<a class="list-group-item" data-bind="click: $parent.onResourceTimeSelect, css: { disabled: isActive == 1 }, style: { background: isSelected == 1 ? '#ddd' : '' }"></a>
```

Which gives me the object of the clicked resource.

```
onResourceTimeSelect: function (data, e) {

}
```

`data` is the object. There is property `isSelected` which if its `1` it should unbind the click event.

```
if (data['isSelected'] == 1) {

}
```

How can i stop the click event? Tried with `$(data).unbind('click')` , `$(data).click(function () { return false });` and none of them work.

If i write `console.log(data)` in the `if` it does give me the message back so i'm 100% im getting in the `if`.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: So basicly, if the value of isSelected is 1 you want to be able to click the button only once?

Comment: if its meets some the conditions i set the `isSelected` property to 1 and change the color of the anchor tag. What i want is to stop the "second click"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data-bind="click: isSelected == 1 ? function() {return false;} : $parent.onResourceTimeSelect, css: { disabled: isActive == 1 }, style: { background: isSelected == 1 ? '#ddd' : '' }"
```

Should do the trick, it's basicly putting an if inside the (knockout) click handler. If the value is 1, it will return false, otherwise your function will be executed.

Note: isSelected need to be an observable!

Comment: ugh, didnt think to do it like that. It worked, thanks. Ill accept the answer in 10 mins.

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes we overlook the easy solutions :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd rename your `click` handler to `onClick` and handle the different cases inside the method:

```
self.onClick = function(resourceTime, event) {
  if (resourceTime.isSelected() === 1) {
    return false;
  }

  self.onResourceTimeSelected(resourceTime);
};
```

Benefits:

- Your `click` binding value is easy to read and less prone to (syntax) errors
- The `onClick` naming indicates that there are several ways to handle a click
- If you want to add additional cases later on, you can easily add them in this handler